# Competition-Level Integral (According to Textbook)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Wondering how to solve the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}~dx$$ According to a textbook, it is a "competition level" integral and I have no idea how to get started. Potentially thinking some sort of dummy-variable manipulation as there doesn't seem to be an elementary function solution.